# Fill a vector with zero values

Tags: r, vector

I have a named numeric vector like this:

```
c(`1` = 2, `5` = 3, `6` = 1, `7` = 2, `8` = 1, `9` = 1)
#1 5 6 7 8 9 (names)
#2 3 1 2 1 1 (values)
```

I want to expand the vector so that the names form a sequence of integers and fill the values with `0`.

Here is my expected output:

```
c(`1` = 2, `2` = 0, `3` = 0, `4` = 0, `5` = 3, `6` = 1, `7` = 2, `8` = 1, `9` = 1)
#1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
#2 0 0 0 3 1 2 1 1
```

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you have a named vector?

Comment: Can you post valid R code to create your data? It's not clear if you have `names <- c(1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9); values <- c(2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1)` or if you have `vector <- c("1" = 2, "5" = 3, "6" = 1, ...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution using name based indexing:

```
vec = c("1" = 2, "5" = 3, "6" = 1, "7" = 2, "8" = 1, "9" = 1)

newvec = double(9);
names(newvec) = 1:9
newvec[names(vec)] = vec;    

newvec

# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
# 2 0 0 0 3 1 2 1 1
```